# simple_form I'm getting No input found for citext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a basic text input in the simple_form:

```
= f.input :title, label: "Name:", placeholder: "New make"
```

I fetch this exception when I'm trying to render the view:

```
No input found for citext
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just specify input type:

```
= f.input :title, label: "Name:", placeholder: "New make", as: :string
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also put following line in the initializer to define custom input mappings.

```
SimpleForm::FormBuilder.map_type :citext, to: SimpleForm::Inputs::TextInput
```

Comment: Thanks this answer. It should be the accepted answer (though it was added a year later, so... :))

Comment: I actually used `SimpleForm::FormBuilder.map_type :citext, to: SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput` which gives a regular text input, rather than a textarea.

Comment: The best solution if you have a bunch of forms with such fields